# Why netlify-lambda logs an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when using async/await on Promises?

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, es6-promise, netlify

I'm trying to create a [lambda function on Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/) and I'm using their [Netlify Lambda CLI](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda) for that.

Now, I'm experiencing an issue when using async/await on Promises because it logs an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even though I'm using try/catch.

Here's a demo:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
        const data = await response.json();

        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: data.value
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Log:

```
netlify-lambda: Starting server
Lambda server is listening on 9000
Hash: 533f41e1d4248894ae20
Version: webpack 4.26.1
Time: 966ms
Built at: 11/28/2018 10:59:44 PM
  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
test.js  18.3 KiB       0  [emitted]  test
Entrypoint test = test.js
[0] external "stream" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[1] external "zlib" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[2] external "url" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[3] external "http" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[4] external "https" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[5] ./test.js + 1 modules 40.8 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./test.js 1.14 KiB [built]
    | ../node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs 39.6 KiB [built]
Request from ::1: GET /test
Response with status 200 in 685 ms.
(node:99167) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at callback (/Users/nunoarruda/Desktop/test/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:22:42)
    at /Users/nunoarruda/Desktop/test/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:41:21
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
(node:99167) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:99167) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/43

Why netlify-lambda logs an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when using async/await on Promises?
How can I fix this?

Comment: I was able to get it working after some testing and have shown it in my answer, but am waiting on the [confirmation from Netlify if this is what they also expect](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/43#issuecomment-444718610).

Comment: Netlify has confirmed there should be no callback on an async function call on netlify functions either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With the new Node.js 8.10 runtime, there are new handler types that can be declared with the “async” keyword or can return a promise directly.

In the AWS docs the v8.10 supports async/await and the new default at Netlify is now using this version. [In the AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/), the examples show these two new handler types removing the use of the callback. We should do the same in our functions using Netlify.

I was able to remove the error message locally using the code below without using the callback:

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
        if (!response.ok) { // NOT res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300
            return { statusCode: response.status, body: response.statusText };
        }
        const data = await response.json();

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: data.value
            // if you want to return whole json string
            // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            // body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err); // output to netlify function log
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: err.message // Could be a custom message or object i.e. JSON.stringify(err)
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reasoning for removing `async`, `await`?

_"since `node-fetch` uses a Promise."_ doesn't make sense

Comment: @8eecf0d2 I was really messed up on my assumptions at first. I was also using a very old version of the CLI  for my test. Starting over with this edit.

Comment: What i was trying to say (poorly ) was that without async/await you can have the handler return a promise directly. But, this answer deserved the solution for `async/await` since that is what he is asking. Callbacks should be removed.

Comment: I updated the [issue here](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/43#issuecomment-444618311) to show the working example of returning a promise rather than the `async` function handler.